# Reversed Stacked bar chart in R leads to weird positioning

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I am trying to create a stacked bar plot in R, and to reverse the order.

```
df <- structure(list(HouseholdEarnings = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 2L
), .Label = c("Below $2,000 per month", "$2,000 - $3,999", "$4,000 - $5,999", 
"$6,000 - $7,999", "$8,000 - $9,999", "$10,000 & above"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor"))), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Based on solutions from other threads, putting `geom_col(position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE))` solved the issue.

```
df %>% group_by(HouseholdEarnings) %>% summarise(Count = n()) %>% mutate(Proportion=Count/sum(Count), group='All') %>%
  as.data.frame() %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, round, digits = 2) %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill=HouseholdEarnings, y=Proportion, x=group)) +
  geom_col(position = position_stack(reverse = T), color = "black") +
  geom_text(aes(label=paste0(Proportion*100, "%")),
                position=position_stack(vjust=0.5), colour="white",size=3) +
  coord_flip()
```

However, now my labels are out of position (still in the original positions):

[image]

It is fine without using `reverse = T`:

```
df %>% group_by(HouseholdEarnings) %>% summarise(Count = n()) %>% mutate(Proportion=Count/sum(Count), group='All') %>%
  as.data.frame() %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, round, digits = 2) %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill=HouseholdEarnings, y=Proportion, x=group)) +
  geom_col(position = position_stack(), color = "black") +
  geom_text(aes(label=paste0(Proportion*100, "%")),
                position=position_stack(vjust=0.5), colour="white",size=3) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Edit: I realize that only the labels are still fixed to their original positions, so is there any way to flip them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass `reverse = TRUE` in your `geom_text` too:

```r
df %>% group_by(HouseholdEarnings) %>% summarise(Count = n()) %>% mutate(Proportion=Count/sum(Count), group='All') %>%
  as.data.frame() %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, round, digits = 2) %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill=HouseholdEarnings, y=Proportion, x=group)) +
  geom_col(position = position_stack(reverse = T), color = "black") +
  geom_text(aes(label=paste0(Proportion*100, "%")),
            position=position_stack(reverse = TRUE, vjust = 0.5), colour="white",size=3) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: That works, I just realized that only the labels are still fixed in their original position. So reversing them works! Thanks!

Comment: Glad you figure it out ;) These kind of small mistakes can drive you crazy !